# How to add elements of a 1D NumPy array to NumPy subarrays with the same index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Let's say I have a NumPy array `a` with shape `(3, 5, 7)` and a 1D NumPy array `l` with shape `(3, 1)`. I want to add the 0th element of `l` to the 0th subarray in `a`, the 1st element of `l` to the 1st subarray of `a`, and the 2nd element of `l` to the 2nd and last subarray of `a`.

For instance, if `l = [[30 40 50]]`, then I want `a[0] += 30`, `a[1] += 40`, `a[2] += 50`.

I know that to achieve this, I can easily do the following:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i] += l[i]
```

but I was wondering if there's a way to do this with pure NumPy, no `for` loops required. Trying `np.add(a, l)` invariably creates the error `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5,7) (3,1)` and trying the following:

```
def add_arrs(a, l):
    return a + l

a = np.apply_along_axis(add_arrs, 0, a, l)
```

gives me a final shape of `(3, 3, 5, 7)`, which is not what I want. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**  I figured it out:

```
a = np.apply_along_axis(np.add, 0, a, l.T)[0]
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` does not improve speed

Comment: I'm not sure why `l` is nested.  If it weren't the `[0]` wouldn't be necessary, or the `.T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [7]: a = np.arange(3*5*7).reshape(3,5,7)
In [8]: b = np.array([[30,40,50]])
In [9]: b.shape
Out[9]: (1, 3)
```

That leading 1 dimension doesn't help; you have to transpose anyways

```
In [10]: b = np.array([30,40,50])
In [11]: b.shape
Out[11]: (3,)
```

The broadcasting works fine if `b` is (3,1,1) shape:

```
In [12]: a += b[:,None,None]
In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array([[[ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36],
        [ 37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43],
        [ 44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50],
        [ 51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57],
        [ 58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64]],

       [[ 75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81],
        [ 82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88],
        [ 89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95],
        [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102],
        [103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],

       [[120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126],
        [127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133],
        [134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140],
        [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147],
        [148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154]]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is so much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here's the answer:

```
a = np.apply_along_axis(np.add, 0, a, l.T)[0]
```